# Private folder in public repository

Tags: git, github, repository

Is it possible to create a private folder that will be in a public repository?

I want something on hand on the remote server, but I don't want everyone to have access to it.

Therefore, I would like to have this as a private folder. Is this setting possible? Have any of you tried to do something like that?

Comment: No, it is not possible with a single repository. It might be possible to do something similar with submodules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot have different public/private settings within one repository. The closest thing I can think of would be to keep the repositories separate and use submodules to create a unified directory tree, but I can’t judge if that makes sense for your workflow.